# dos batch process to move files based on file's modified date in 'yyyymmdd' and based on file's extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i have number of files having different extensions in a folder.
i need a DOS batch file that will:

1. move files of same extension in a directory to the 'extension'-named folder

and another DOS batch file that will:

2. move all files in a directory having same date to a 'yyyymmdd' folder

Comment: You already did a nice deconstruction of the problem, you surely have solved some parts of it already, no? Show us some code, what you tried!

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS? The command line in Windows has nothing to do with "DOS".

Comment: @kabi, these two questions have many answers here, please use search before asking.